# Microsoft Store submission API return 401

Tags: azure, windows-dev-center

i've tyr to use https://manage.devcenter.microsoft.com/v1.0/my/applications to get my app list. But its always returning

```
{
    "code": "Unauthorized",
    "message": "Identity cannot be authorized. CorrelationId: 1845486a-3a9b-4e70-a5a3-f8dcaf2a2268"
}
```

I've already follow the instruction until i've finnaly can get token form microsof azure AD. It is somethin i miss?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.